# Sony Experia 5 Android Build.Class info

Tags: android, mobile-development, sony, mobile-devices, sony-xperia

Can anyone help me about the Sony Experia 5 Android Build.Class info ?

the output if it print the
`Build.BRAND + Build.MANUFACTURER + Build.MODEL + Build.HARDWARE + Build.FINGERPRINT + Build.PRODUCT + Build.BOARD + Build.BOOTLOADER + Build.SERIAL + Build.HOST + Build.DEVICE` , etc.

Cause i didnt have that device and i have several problem with my project regarding the emulator preventing function.